Origin of the phrase "continuous determination"
This question is motivated by Continuous determination of the argument.
I had not heard the English term "continuous determination" before, but it seems to be used in the context of multivalued functions in complex analysis like

the argument of a complex number,
the logarithm of a complex number,
the $n$-th root of a complex number.

A determination of such a multivalued function on an open $U \subset \mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is certainly a function with domain $U$ which selects, or determines, for each $z \in U$ a specific value of the argument, logarithm etc. This also explains what a continuous determination is.
In other words, a continuous determination is nothing else than a branch of the corresponing multivalued function.
But where is the origin of this term?
My guess: It is of French origin. Googling "détermination continue" produces a large number  of hits. Can anybody confirm this? Is "détermination continue" a standard notation in French?
